# xctool doesn't run with the requested iOS version

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctool

I am running iOS tests on Circle CI using Xcode 6.4 and iOS 8.4 with this command:

`xctool -workspace ios.xcworkspace -scheme ios test -sdk iphonesimulator8.4`

But when the simulator runs, it fails to run my tests and I receive this error:

> Test did not run: The simulator failed to start, or the TEST_HOST
>   application failed to run. Simulator error: Exception encountered
>   connecting to CoreSimulatorBridge: Unable to connect to
>   CoreSimulatorBridge

Looking at the logs, it looks like the simulator actually tries to run against iOS 9:

> run-test iosTests.xctest (iphonesimulator9.0, iPhone 4s, application-test)

Is there a way to force it to run on iOS 8.4 so the tests would run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue recently on Circle CI. I'm not sure if it's related to xctool's newest version (0.2.7) or not, but adding this fixed it for me:

`-destination platform='iOS Simulator,OS=8.4,name=iPhone 6'`

So the full command in your case should be:

`xctool -workspace ios.xcworkspace -scheme ios test -sdk iphonesimulator8.4 -destination platform='iOS Simulator,OS=8.4,name=iPhone 6'`